# How to see what drive letters are mapped for network drive?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, networking, command-line-interface, mappeddrive

Is there a way to see what drive letters are in use for network drives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open a command prompt and type:
`net use`
and press enter. That will list all active drive mappings.

Answer (score 3):

From a command prompt type: net use.

Comment: sorry joe : didn't refreshed the page and had a phone call :-) !